# dblink and update between 2 databases

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update

I'm using postgresql and I need to do an update in the 2ND Database based on the first Database. I also need to use dblink

This is the row I need to do the update from:

```
pid  |   pname  |  pcompany  |  clocation  |  did  |   name
 1       Pirates    Argos        London        1       Mary
```

This is the 2ND Database table 1 in which the Update has to be made to

```
pid  |   pname        |  pcompany  |
 1       Ba Ba Black      Argos
```

in this 2nd database one can see that pname is Ba Ba Black. This needs to be changed to Pirates like the 1st database by comparing the pid

so if db1 ta1 = 1 and so is db2 tb2 =1 then Ba Ba Black in db2 tb2 changes to Pirates

I am using this code:

```
UPDATE tb2
SET name = ta1.name
WHERE pid = 1
FROM dblink('port=5432, dbname=db1 user=postgres  password=12345')
AS t1 (a character(50));
```

but it's giving me this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 4: FROM dblink('port=5432, dbname=db1 user=postgres  password=1...
```

Any fix how I can arrange things pleasE? thanks

EDIT:

If for example I make it comparing pid AND pcompany it would be better 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have your FROM and WHERE mixed up:

```
UPDATE tb2
SET name = ta1.name
FROM dblink('port=5432, dbname=db1 user=postgres  password=12345')
AS t1 (a character(50))
WHERE pid = 1;
```

Comment: I have another Error with that:
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ta1"
LINE 2: SET name = ta1.name